# Soy nuevo en esto y no se por donde empezar, me pueden guiar, es de la universidad

Tags: variables, algoritmos, programación-funcional, pseint, pseudocódigo

¿Cómo realizaría el análisis y diseño que permita calcular la velocidad final de un automóvil conociendo como datos de entrada la velocidad inicial, la aceleración y el tiempo? La fórmula que aplicaría sería Vf=Vo+a*t (Vf= Velocidad final, Vo = Velocidad inicial, t=tiempo)